# How overload optional parameter in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have interface like this:

```js
export interface Actions {
      [ActionEnum.FOO](someParam: {}, payload: string): void
      [ActionEnum.BAR](someParam: {}, payload: PayloadType): void
      [ActionEnum.BAZ](someParam: {}): void
    }
```

As u can see second parameter is optional.

I have a function:

```js
type Dispatch = <K extends keyof Actions, P extends Parameters<Actions[K]>[1]>(type: K,  payload?: P) => ReturnType<Actions[K]>
```

First parameter is `ActionEnum`. Second is payload from same action.
It is works. TS check type of payload correctly if I pass payload. But I may not pass payload if even necessary. No TS errors for this case.

How say to TS that in specific case second parameter optional or not. For example:

```
Dispatch(ActionEnum.FOO) // error, because we have second parameter in Action
Dispatch(ActionEnum.BAZ) // no error, because we have not second parameter in Action
```

Comment: I dont see 2nd parameter option in `Actions` interface, can you explain?

Comment: I think you want something [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: There's a cleaner way to write that, but I can't think of it right now